# Angular Elements doesn't include Material Theme css properly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-elements

I have included Angular Material in my angular element project. I have included all the references how the documentation suggests, but when I build seems like angular the material theme isn't included at all.

This is the link for watching what I mean: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/3JIbOfnyKiefS31N?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Material module for wrapping all the components

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatSelectModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

AppModule

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Injector, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {GalleryComponent} from './gallery/gallery.component';
import {createCustomElement} from '@angular/elements';

import {ImageService} from './gallery/image.service';
import { ImageComponent } from './gallery/image/image.component';
import { ImageDetailsComponent } from './gallery/image-details/image-details.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MaterialModule} from './material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GalleryComponent,
    ImageComponent,
    ImageDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [GalleryComponent],
  providers: [ImageService],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const custom = createCustomElement(GalleryComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('slim-gallery', custom);
  }
}
```

The Style

```css
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";

body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.basic-container {
  padding: 30px;
}

.version-info {
  font-size: 8pt;
  float: right;
}
```

Component template html

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: check `node_modules/@angular/material` exists?

Comment: yes because the project compiles successfullly

Comment: were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue.
Try adding this line (this is for indigo theme) on you app.component.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

And then on your component ts use encapsulation none, like follows:

```
@Component({
 ...,
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested in the solution. My problmen was caused by ngZone: 'noop' in the main.ts file. It disables change detection.

So changing this

platformBrowserDynamic()
.bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
ngZone: 'noop'
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
to this

platformBrowserDynamic()
.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
solved my problem with Angular Material Elements.

Answer (score -1):

You have imported this:

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material';
```

But the [Material API documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api) specifies the import like this:

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

On stackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3l12yn

Comment: If I remove that module, the result is the same. The problem could be Angular Elements but I don't know how resolve

Comment: Would you upload to stackblitz? (plunker doesn't says anything)
I have copy&paste your code to stackBlitz and after that change the import path and works.
Or remove this part : <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
and add placeholder

  `<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>`

Comment: console says: ERROR
Error: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "slim-gallery" has already been used with this registry

Comment: index.html contains: <slim-gallery></slim-gallery>
if you check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3l12yn
you can see <my-app>loading</my-app>.
Which refers to **app.component.ts:**

`@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})`

Comment: I think I can't replicate on stackbliz because Angular create 2 different build(es5 and es2015), so the slim-gallery component is declared twice

Comment: **1.** I had made a components folder.  
**2.** I put there "gallery" related files.  
**3.** I added routing, gallery will be the default path `{path: '', component: GalleryComponent}`.  
**4.** added gallery.component and routing to app.module.ts.  
**5.** app.component.ts got `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`  and `constructor(private router: Router){}`.  
**6.** app.component.html got `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.  
**7.** remove this part `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,` from gallery.component.ts